# Why does release mode affect on Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP .NET application.
I set culture in Application_Begin request:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = myCulture;
```

When I get current culture from page, it is `myCulture` in debug mode and it is "en-GB" in release mode.

I don't understand why Release mode affects on `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

I use VS2010 and .NET 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Where does myCulture come from? Is there any difference between debug/release mode?

Comment: it's supposed to get culture from request (querystring), but I tried to hardcore culture to solve problem.

There are no differences between release and debug, related to culture at least.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem out. I use javaScript compressor in Release mode and it change culture of current thread if you don't specify your own culture.

So, be careful with using javascript comressors =)